# nginx proxy pass error with django [DOCKER]

Tags: django, regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a django backend running on docker using this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./classificacao-frontend
    container_name: frontend
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=services
      - POSTGRES_USER=services_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecret
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped

  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./pge-services/docker/dev/python/Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    volumes:
      - /docker/classificacao/shared_files:/shared_files
      - /docker/classificacao/static_files:/static_files
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=pge.settings_dev
      - POSTGRES_NAME=services
      - POSTGRES_USER=services_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecret
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - CAIPORA_ADDRESS=http://10.0.134.130
      - USER_SYSTEM=/api/usuario-sistema
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
  proxy:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: proxy
    mem_limit: 128m
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
        - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - ./config/nginx.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.htpasswd 
        - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
        - /docker/classificacao/pge-services:/code
        - /docker/classificacao/shared_files:/shared_files
        - /docker/classificacao/static_files:/static_files
    ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443
```

The django backend (here as the backend service on docker-compose.yml) is being called as the /backend url on the nginx proxy:

```
upstream back{
 server backend:8000;
}

location /backend/ {
        set $accept_language "pt-br";
        proxy_pass http://back;    
}
```

The problem is the django, running on port 8000, has the /admin and /api endpoints on it. When i hit my proxy at /backend, i.e http://localhost/backend/admin, it tries to access django at /backend/admin, which doesn't exists (it should be only /admin). If i try only /backend, it shows a Not Found: / in the backend log. Also for /backend/api.

It should proxy_pass to the django container, removing the backend from the url, but keeping everything after /backend, like if i type /backend/admin, it should only pass /admin (and whatever is after /admin, like /admin/users, etc). The same for /api.

Not Found: /
Not Found: /backend/api
Not Found: /backend/admin

how can i solve this? i'm pretty sure it's just the nginx location configuration, but i'm unable to fix it.

[EDIT 1]

i tried modifying the location to:

```
location /backend/ {
set $accept_language "pt-br";
proxy_pass http://backend:8000/admin/;
}
```

but then it falls back to /admin, without the backend:8000

and the location / is proxied to another container, as in my nginx.conf is :

```
location / {
        set $accept_language "pt-br";
        proxy_pass http://caipora:8080/;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```